# History or Histories?

Tags: grammatical-number

For a website I am going to show a list of changes to various fields shown for various components on the screen.
There is some question as to whether this is a 'Fields History', 'Field Histories', or something else entirely.

What is grammatically correct here?

Comment: None is grammatically incorrect. 'Field history' is perhaps the most idiomatic, using the singular rather than the plural attributive _field_ and the professional-sounding mass usage _history_, but 'field histories' brings out the plural nature involved better. 'Fields histories' (histories of the various fields) is probably the most logical and least natural-sounding.

Comment: To @EdwinAshford's comment I would add only that you might want to use *revision histories* rather than *histories*. So, I would go with *field revision histories*, which also might address the field-fields issue in that *field revision histories* implies to me multiple fields.

Answer (score 2):

As Edwin Ashworth's comment from 20 months ago observes, the issue you raise isn't fundamentally one of grammar, since various combinations of "field[s]" and "histor[y/ies]" do not offend against grammatical correctness, depending on how you frame them.

Idiomatically, however, "Field History" and "Field Histories" seem the least awkward and most intuitively reasonable choices. The choice between *History* and *Histories* depends on whether you understand your presentation of changes to the various fields to be "a history of the changes to the various fields [or to each field] shown" or whether you prefer to conceive of it as "a collection of histories—one for each field." There is no logical reason to prefer one interpretation over the other.

As for *Field* versus *Fields*, there is again no ironclad rule requiring you to choose one over the other. A similar situation might arise if you were trying to describe a cookbook (or multiple cookbooks) dedicated to recipes for desserts: "dessert cookbook," "desserts cookbook," dessert cookbooks," and "desserts cookbooks" are defensible, depending on the situation and your own stylistic preference.

Having said that, I note that many English phrases take the choice out of the speakers (or writer's) hands by endorsing—through popular usage—the singular form of the first word in such pairs. For example, a person who watches birds, is by general agreement a "birdwatcher," not a "birds watcher"; a game of cards is a "card game," not a "cards game"; and a house built of bricks is a "brick house" not a "bricks house." It seems to me that the cumulative effect of this preference for the singular first word in English is to push the needle of intuitive naturalness toward "Field History" and "Field Histories" and away from "Fields History" and "Fields Histories."

Comment: Well, its been a while, but we did end up with a variation on "Field Histories" as you suggest, based upon the comments of  @richard-kayser.  We went with Field Revisions History, and everyone was pleased.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

However, in more specific contexts, the plural form can also be histories e.g. in reference to various types of histories or a collection of histories.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Your answer has not quite addressed  the specific question asked here. You might want to edit it give a specific answer.